# Why pulseaudio's pactl doesn't work

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio

I have installed fedora yesterday. I was using arch all my linux-life, fedora is good too. But I have only one problem. For using my headpanel analog sound i run script with pulseaudio module setup:

```
pactl load-module module-detect
```

But it doesn't work on Fedora. I have an error every time:

```
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

What i need to do?

Comment: FYI, [cross-posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to multiple Stack Exchange sites is [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  But perhaps this is a better location than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828696/why-fedora-cant-load-module-detect ? I saw your other post first, please see my comment there.

Comment: Hey, it would be better if you edit this question with all the information you have (your cross-posted question at StackOverflow already has one close vote ... that site is mostly for programming questions).  A more specific title here would help others understand the specific problem.  Other info you could provide here would be the output of `pactl info` and perhaps a subset of the output of `pactl list short`.  Describing more of what  you want would helpful too, e.g., what specifically isn't working with your sound?  Is there no sound, wrong sound, etc.?

Comment: I load module-detect to make the analog output available in the sound menu.

Comment: Sorry, it could just be my ignorance, but what is "headpanel analog sound"?  Is that an app, part of an app?  Does "normal" sound work for you, i.e., if you play a YouTube video in your browser, can you hear the sound?  What is "script", and why is it necessary?  What does it do?  Again, what is the output of `pactl info`?  We need more info about what you trying to do and what the exact problems are.

Comment: When I go to the sound settings I can choose output device. Without running `module-detect` there is no analog output for my pc.

Comment: So in sound settings you **can** select a working output device?

Comment: No.
I can't choose it without script

Comment: If you create a fresh user account, does it show the same symptoms, or can you select sound normally with it, i.e., without using a script?

Comment: No. I can't select even on a new user

Comment: And the output of `pactl info` is?